# I can't do "git push origin master"

Tags: git, bitbucket

when I try to do git push origin master I always get one of these messages I tried bitbucket only is there is a problem with git commands or something?

[error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogSPT.jpg)

[error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi0ds.jpg)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: the full detailed errors on the two images

Comment: Did you try to fetch and merge first, as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the first error message, make sure you've properly generated an RSA key pair and uploaded the public key to bitbucket in your settings. The second error message is appearing because you need to run `git pull` before you run `git push` in order to update the repository.